# SQLDev not showing proper font definition

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to improve the look and feel of this IDE. How can I see the fonts in high definition?

Here's a screenshot so you can understand me:

[image: example]

In red I have circled what I am seeing with bad resolution; in yellow I have highlighted what I see well.

I did some config as this [link](https://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/configuring-oracle-sql-developer-for-windows-7/) suggests.

Comment: I've had this happen too when switching screens from my laptop.  I never figured it out but I strongly suspect that it has something to do with the automatic DPI scaling of windows that Microsoft added from Vista on.  Some explanation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt843498(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: try Java 9 https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/08/look-and-feel-feel-free-to-go-crazy/